# execute remote php scripts using php.exe

Tags: php, command-line-interface, remote-server

Im executing a PHP script using php.exe command.
All the script executes well, but under certain condition (using if condition) I must call a second one in a remote server.

I tried adding this line "header('Location:http:// XXX .php');" that works well if I use iexplorer, but this line do not works if I use CLI "php.exe".

Anyone knows how can I call a remote script using PHP.EXE command?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are thinking about this:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php